# Jest testing Vue lifecycle or async method doesn't await for result in unit-testing

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to implement unit testing with Jest for a Vue component which on created() lifecycle calls a function which has axios who runs async.
The thing is, the created is being triggered, but the value of the object that sits in the component data section won't show it's new value. (remains undefined, tested also when initialized with some other value then undefined)

I've used many solutions that was offered around here but nothing was 100% accurate to the situation I'm dealing with.

Products component:

```
   data() {
      return {
        products: undefined,
        countries: undefined,
        fields: undefined,
        selectedItem: undefined,
        alert: undefined,
     };
  },
  methods: {
    async getProducts() {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000");
        this.products = res.data.products;
        this.countries = res.data.countries;
        this.fields = Object.keys(this.products[0]).splice(1);
        this.fields.push({ key: "Edit", label: "Click & Edit" });
        } 
        catch (error) {
        this.toggleAlert(true, "Failed to retrieve data from server");
        console.log(error);
        }
    },
  }
  created() {
    this.getProducts();
  }
```

testfile:

```
// create an extended `Vue` constructor
   const localVue = createLocalVue();
// install plugins as normal 
   localVue.use(BootstrapVue);
   describe("Testing Products component:", () => {
       test("checks the incoming data from api", async () => {
          const wrapper = shallowMount(Products, { localVue });
          await flushPromises();
          console.log(wrapper.vm.$data.products, "products"); //prints undefined instead of an array
          expect(wrapper.vm.$data.products).not.toBe(undefined);
  });
});
```

Comment: Don't use real requests in unit tests. They are long and unreliable, you cannot control when they are finished.

Comment: when using them by declaring functions in a basic JavaScript file, it works every single time, but not through the Vue Component. what's the difference between the two ways?

Comment: Which functions? It's unknown what exactly you're trying to do with basic file, but here you perform a request that takes a considerable amount of time and expect it to be completed within a couple of milliseconds (this is what flushPromises does).